# Difference between DirectChannel and FluxMessageChannel

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor

I was reading about Spring Integration's `FluxMessageChannel` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/channel.html#flux-message-channel) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#fluxmessagechannel-and-reactivestreamsconsumer), but I still don't understand exactly what are the differences between using a `DirectChannel` and `FluxMessageChannel` when using Project Reactor. Since the DirectChannel is stateless and controlled by its pollers, I'd expect the `FluxMessageChannel` to not be needed. I'm trying to understand when exactly should I use each and why, when speaking on Reactive Streams applications that are implemented with Spring Integration.

I currently have a reactive project that uses `DirectChannel`, and it seems to work fine, even the documentation says:

> the flow behavior is changed from an imperative push model to a reactive pull model

I'd like to understand when to use each of the channels and what is the exact difference when working with Reactive Streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DirectChannel` does not have any poller and its implementation is very simple: as long as a message is sent to it, the handler is called. In the same caller's thread:

public class DirectChannel extends AbstractSubscribableChannel {

```
private final UnicastingDispatcher dispatcher = new UnicastingDispatcher();

private volatile Integer maxSubscribers;

/**
 * Create a channel with default {@link RoundRobinLoadBalancingStrategy}.
 */
public DirectChannel() {
    this(new RoundRobinLoadBalancingStrategy());
}
```

Where that `UnicastingDispatcher` is:

```
public final boolean dispatch(final Message<?> message) {
    if (this.executor != null) {
        Runnable task = createMessageHandlingTask(message);
        this.executor.execute(task);
        return true;
    }
    return this.doDispatch(message);
}
```

(There is no `executor` option for the `DirectChannel`)

```
private boolean doDispatch(Message<?> message) {
    if (tryOptimizedDispatch(message)) {
        return true;
    }

...

protected boolean tryOptimizedDispatch(Message<?> message) {
    MessageHandler handler = this.theOneHandler;
    if (handler != null) {
        try {
            handler.handleMessage(message);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw IntegrationUtils.wrapInDeliveryExceptionIfNecessary(message,
                    () -> "Dispatcher failed to deliver Message", e);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That's why I call it " imperative push model". The caller is this case is going to wait until the handler finishes its job. And if you have a big flow, everything is going to be stopped in the sender thread until a sent message has reached the end of the flow of direct channels. In two simple words: the publisher is in charge for the whole execution and it is blocked in this case. You haven't faced any problems with your solution based on the `DirectChannel` just because you didn't use reactive non-blocking threads yet like Netty in WebFlux or MongoDB reactive driver.

The `FluxMessageChannel` was really designed for Reactive Streams purposes where the subscriber is in charge for handling a message which it pulls from the `Flux` on demand. This way just after sending the publisher is free to do anything else. Just because it is already a subscriber responsibility to handle the message.

I would say it is definitely OK to use `DirectChannel` as long as your handlers are not blocking. As long as they are blocking you should go with `FluxMessageChannel`. Although don't forget that there are other channel types for different tasks: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations